# default value in Vue.js select type

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to set a default value in a Select type in Vue.js

here is the definition:

```
this.LengthId = {
    model: 'LengthId',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Length',
    values: putQueueLength,
    selectOptions: { value: 'Id', name: 'Name' },
    required: true,
    validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.required,

  }
```

the **putQueueLength** values attribute which populates the drop down is defined here.  A simple population.

```
  var putQueueLength = function (values, model) {
    return [{ Id: 1, Name: '12 Months', Id: 2, Name: '24 Months' }];
  };
```

So just a couple of values in the drop down with an ID and a Name.

I'd simply like to default that drop down list with the id value of '1',  text value '12 Months'

How would I do this?

Comment: Hi are you trying to set default type to properties:
`props:{ myProp:{type:[String,Boolean],default:'this is my default'} }`

Comment: Alternatively you are looking for `v-for` loop `<option v-for="(v,i) in putQueueLength" v-bind:key="i">{{v}}</option>`

Comment: No, this is just a modal form that pops up waiting for the user to enter information

Comment: there is not enough code to determine what ur error is